# Repairing gaps in polyline to polygonize

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have a large, complex coastal outline (polyline) that I am trying to polygonize. It won't work so I suspect there is a gap somewhere or some other error. Any ideas on a workflow to repair the outline and polygonize it without trawling the polyline section by section looking for gaps? It is over 100 MB so most processes are slow.

Comment: To determine if the polygonize was successful for each feature, you can try `is_closed($geometry)` by the Field Calculator.

Comment: You could try with the _snap_ method of the _v.clean_ tool and an appropriate _threshold_.

Comment: Another method would be to buffer the line by a small amount. That should create a closed polygon with an inner ring. Use the Advanced Digitizing tool "Delete Ring" to remove the inner ring.